# Task prioritization when yielding from spawn method running on strand executor

Tags: c++, boost, synchronization, asio

I'd like to analyze the ordering of boost.asio calls using strand.

Consider the following scenario. First, a coroutine that uses the strand is called by `boost::asio::spawn` (task 1), it's running exclusively since I use strand until it gets suspended cooperatively when instruction pointer reach ***, and the scheduler that runs on the thread executes the next handler (task 2).

Task 2 uses the same strand but it's called by `boost::asio::post`. this call guarantee that this task get exclusiveness until finished (no yields).

So I expect that in this scenario, the remaining of task 1 won't be executed at least until task 2 finished. is my assumption correct ?

Furthermore, what if while task 2 being executed, more tasks are called on the same strand, does task 1 get priority when task 2 terminates, or there's no guarantee which task is going to take the strand (either task 2 that just return from yield or newer tasks that called)

```
//task1
boost::asio::spawn(strand_, [=](const auto& yield) {
  ...
  ..
  .
  auto response = sendRequest(request, yield);   //(***)
  ...
  ..
  .
}

//task 2 
boost::asio::post(strand_, [&]() {
  ... 
  ..
  .
}

//task 3
boost::asio::post(strand_, [&]() {
  ... 
  ..
  .
}
```

Comment: Much better wording than [before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77096475/85371). Still it would help to be precise. E.g. "I use strand until reach a yield that take the thread to execute the next task (task 2)" - no such thing happens. You don't "reach a yield". You suspend the coroutine. Nothing "takes the thread". Instead the scheduler that runs on the thread executes the next handler (which in context is expected to be task 2)

Comment: thanks for you comments (as always), revised the wording. feel free to edit if you still think it's not clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I expect that in this scenario, the remaining of task 1 won't be executed at least until task 2 finished. is my assumption correct ?

Yes

> Furthermore, what if while task 2 being executed, more tasks are called on the same strand, does task 1 get priority when task 2 terminates, or there's no guarantee which task is going to take the strand (either task 2 that just return from yield or newer tasks that called)

If by "tasks are called" you mean "handlers are posted" (or equivalently: "async operations are initiated"), yes. All the tasks on a strand are executed in order they are posted.

This is documented here: [Order Of Handler Invocation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context__strand.html#boost_asio.reference.io_context__strand.order_of_handler_invocation):

> #### Order of handler invocation
>
> Given: a strand object `s`
>
> - an object `a` meeting completion handler requirements
> - an object `a1` which is an arbitrary copy of `a` made by the implementation
> - an object `b` meeting completion handler requirements
> - an object `b1` which is an arbitrary copy of `b` made by the implementation
>
> if any of the following conditions are true:
>
> - `s.post(a)` happens-before `s.post(b)`
> - `s.post(a)` happens-before `s.dispatch(b)`, where the latter is performed outside the strand
> - `s.dispatch(a)` happens-before `s.post(b)`, where the former is performed outside the strand
> - `s.dispatch(a)` happens-before `s.dispatch(b)`, where both are performed outside the strand
>
> then `asio_handler_invoke(a1, &a1)` happens-before `asio_handler_invoke(b1, &b1)`.

In your case the happens-before is present (because you know that task1's continuation MUST have been posted before task2 could be entered).